# NEAR cli contract call works but fails when called from js sdk with same params

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

I have a contract running on the Near blockchain. It accepts a deposit as a payment and has the [payable] attribute on the method.
Calling this contract from the Near cli with like this - `near call sam2.testnet process_play_request --accountId sam2.testnet --deposit 0.005` works fine and returns hello world.

```
let res = await contract.process_play_request(
    {},
    undefined, // attached GAS (optional)
    nearAPI.utils.format.parseNearAmount("0.005")
);
```

However calling the same contract, with the same account logged in, using the above JS code throws the following error `Error: {} at Object.parseRpcError`
Other methods on the same contract work fine it's only when i try to use the Deposit functionality that it seems to fall apart. Attaching the proper GAS amount still returns the same error.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong with the JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Following on from Serhii's answer above. The actual error that was thrown was that my app didn't have permission to transfer tokens.
I had to logout of my app and re-login to the sam2 account, it added full key permissions, meaning the JS posted in my question works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `near-api-js` can not parse error from JSON RPC. Can you please go to your `node-modules/near-api-js` folder and add a `console.log(errorObject)` here: https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/ee975a1edd84dff955302453fbcca1413d362bb7/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js#L20
Maybe the error itself will help us to understand what is happening.